# What's the mechanism behind the transformation of $\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^{n}\binom{k}{j}$ to $\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I know that sum of the $n$-th row in pascals triangle is equal to $2^n$. But I couldn't get, how can sum
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=j}^{n}\binom{k}{j}$$
be transformed into
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^k.$$

Also our professor told us, that there is a general rule, which allows to make index changes in sums of those form. So, what is the mechanics behind those transformations?

Comment: $$\{(k,j):0\leq j\leq n\text{ and }j\leq k\leq n\}=\{(k,j):0\leq k\leq n\text{ and }0\leq j\leq k\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just a matter of reversing the order of summation:

$$\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{k}j=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}j=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\;.\tag{1}$$

If you examine the first double summation closely, you’ll see that you’re summing $\binom{k}j$ over all pairs of indices $j$ and $k$ such that $0\le j\le k\le n$, and the second double summation is over exactly the same set of pairs of indices. The second equality holds because $\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}j=2^k$.

The following diagram may help in seeing how the reversal of order of the summations works; it illustrates the case $n=4$.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
&k=0&k=1&k=2&k=3&k=4\\ \hline
j=0&\binom00&\binom10&\binom20&\binom30&\binom40&\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{k}0\\
j=1&&\binom11&\binom21&\binom31&\binom41&\sum_{k=1}^4\binom{k}1\\
j=2&&&\binom22&\binom32&\binom42&\sum_{k=2}^4\binom{k}2\\
j=3&&&&\binom33&\binom43&\sum_{k=3}^4\binom{k}3\\
j=4&&&&&\binom44&\sum_{k=4}^4\binom{k}4\\ \hline
&\sum_{j=0}^0\binom0j&\sum_{j=0}^1\binom1j&\sum_{j=0}^2\binom2j&\sum_{j=0}^3\binom3j&\sum_{j=0}^4\binom4j
\end{array}$$

The inner summation in the first double summation in $(1)$ computes the row sums of this array, and the outer summation then adds these row sums to get the total for the entire array.

The inner summation in the second double summation computes the *column* sums of the array, and the outer summation then adds these column sums to get the total for the entire array.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=j}^n \binom{k}{j}
= \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}
= \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k.
\end{align}
The first step is the most important step. It helps to just sketch out a list of all pairs $(j,k)$ that you are supposed to consider.

Answer (score 0):

It's like applying Fubini's theorem to interchange order of integration. Abstractly, we have
\begin{align}
\sum^n_{j=0}\sum^n_{k=j} \binom{k}{j}  = \int^n_0 \int^n_j \binom{k}{j}\ dc(k) dc(j)
\end{align}
where $dc$ are counting measures. Then applying the usual trick of interchanging orders of integration, we get that
\begin{align}
\int^n_0 \int^n_j \binom{k}{j}\ dc(k) dc(j)= \int^n_0 \int^k_0 \binom{k}{j}\ dc(j)dc(k) = \sum^n_{k=0}\sum^k_{j=0} \binom{k}{j}.
\end{align}
Using the binomial theorem, we have that
\begin{align}
\sum^n_{k=0}\sum^k_{j=0} \binom{k}{j} = \sum^n_{k=0} (1+1)^k = \sum^n_{k=0} 2^k = \frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-2} = 2^{n+1}-1. 
\end{align}